# How do you get a column name and row from table?

Tags: python

I have to write a code where table is represented as dictionary, each key is the name of the column name and each value is the list of items in that column from top row to bottom.

I can use dictionary, list or whatever i want. So i decided to use dictionary

But when i test my code, I am getting this weird error :

```
>diction = {'a' : ['letter of a']}

>my_table = Table()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'new_dict', 'coloumn_name', and 'coloumn_value'
```

Can someone help me with this?

```
class Table():
    '''A class to represent a SQuEaL table'''
    def __init__(self, new_dict, coloumn_name, coloumn_value):
        self._new_dict = new_dict
        self._key = coloumn_name
        self._value = coloumn_value 
   
    def new_dictionary(self):
        return self._new_dict
    
    def get_coloumn_name(self):
        return self._key
    
    def get_coloumn_value(self):
        return self._value
    
    def set_dict(self, new_dict):
        '''(Table, dict of {str: list of str}) -> NoneType
        Populate this table with the data in new_dict.
        The input dictionary must be of the form:
        column_name: list_of_values
        '''        
        # assign empty dictionary
        self._new_dict = {}
    
        # each key represents a coloumn name and each value is list of items 
        # that coloumn_name from top row to bottom(coloum_values)
        self._new_dict += get_coloumn_name[self._key], get_coloumn_value[self._value]
        return
```

Comment: We cant help you if you don't put up any code. You don't need to copy/paste proprietary code - have a go at making a simple set of code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because the `__init__()` function in your class requires 3 arguments - `new_dict`, `coloumn_name`, and `coloumn_value` - and you did not supply them.

Comment: but my set_dict only takes 2 parameters

Comment: @Diana actually, it only takes 1 parameter - `self` refers to the class instance itself. At any rate, though, where did this class come from? What is its purpose? What are you trying to achieve? Have you read the [tutorial on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)?